# Coin toss Game problem in Python and betting against the computer

Tags: python

I wrote this code:

```
#Coin flip Game
import random, sys

print('Heads or Tails')

#These are the variables that keep the number of wins and losses
Wins=0
Losses=0

#this loop starts the game and has the user enter the value for either heads or tails or has them quit the loop. Once the player has chosen it will exit the loop.

while True: #the main game loop
    print('%s Wins, %s Losses' % (Wins, Losses))
    while True: #player input loop
        print('Enter your move: (h)eads or (t)ails or (q)uit')
        playerMove = input()
        if playerMove == 'q':
            sys.exit() #quits the game
            
        if playerMove == 'h' or playerMove == 't':
            break #break out of the player input loop.
            
            
#displays what the player chose. This should print out if you chose heads or tails:
if playerMove == 'h':
        print('Heads versus...')
elif playerMove == 't':
        print('Tails versus...')
    
#display what the computer chose
randomNumber = random.randint(1, 2)
if randomNumber == 1:
    computerMove = 'h'
    print('Heads')
elif randomNumber == 2:
    computerMove = 't'
    print('Tails')
    
#displays whether you won or lost and should show what your win/lose record
if playerMove == computerMove:
    print('Player wins!')
    wins = wins + 1
elif playerMove != computerMove:
    print('Player loses')
    losses = losses + 1
```

How do I fix the problem?

It is supposed to mimic a coin toss. If you guess correctly you win. If you don't you lose.

The results that I am getting are that it goes back to the start of the loop without printing my choice or showing whether I won or lost.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a sufficient error description. What happens and what would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: what output do you get? and what is your desired output? 
In the first block with `while` loop, you have two infinite loop, and your code block after  `#display what the player chose:` is out of the loop. I think this block of code should be inside your outer loop.

Comment: I think everything after the `break` should be part of the first loop and you will have to adjust some names because `win` is not `Win`. Please take care of the indentation when you copy code from somewhere else.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [edit] the question to explain the problem and clearly ask a *specific* question. Note that this is **not a discussion forum**; we are not interested in anyone's background story. Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn how to track down problems yourself, and [mre] for guidance on posting code that is suitable for showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some parts of your code and made some parts more pythonic. But this works now for me.

```py
#Coin flip Game
import random, sys

print('Heads or Tails')

#These are the variables that keep the number of wins and losses
wins = 0
losses = 0

while True: #the main game loop
    print("{wins} Wins, {losses} Losses".format(wins=wins, losses=losses))
    print("Enter your move: (h)eads or (t)ails or (q)uit")
    playerMove = input()
    if playerMove == 'q':
        sys.exit() #quits the game
          
    #display what the player chose:
    if playerMove == 'h':
            print('Heads versus...')
    elif playerMove == 't':
            print('Tails versus...')
    
    #display what the computer chose
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 2)
    if randomNumber == 1:
        computerMove = 'h'
        print('Heads')
    elif randomNumber == 2:
        computerMove = 't'
        print('Tails')
    
    #display and record win/loss record
    if playerMove == computerMove:
        print('Player wins!')
        wins = wins + 1
    elif playerMove != computerMove:
        print('Player loses')
        losses = losses + 1
```

Comment: Excellent! thank you very much. It's much cleaner and easier to understand. I have been programming python for precisely three hours. Thank you very much.

Comment: You updated the old style formatting with `%` to a newer style with `format`. You could go all the way and use an f-string: `print(f"{wins} Wins, {losses} Losses")`

Comment: This code doesn't check for a valid input anymore.